# Why did flagging as very low quality result in audit failure

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits

I came across this [question](https://serverfault.com/review/late-answers/275819) in the later answers review queue. Since it was a link only answer, I chose to flag as very low quality.

Then I got this message:

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. This answer was of very poor quality, and needed significant improvements to be useful – passing over such posts hurts the ability of others to find and answer good questions. Please try to fix such posts by editing, downvoting, closing, or flagging as "very low quality".
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

This suggests flagging as very low quality is one of the acceptable responses, which is what I did. So why did I fail the audit?

Comment: According to my view, you have voted "No action needed", which would trigger a review fail.

Comment: @Sven I certainly did flag as very low quality.

Comment: @Sven I guess the question then is, why did it not register that I flagged the post? I know for a fact that I did chose to flag as very low quality.

Comment: I hate audit reviews.  I particularly hate the "Please take a minute to think about the bad thing you've done" text.  :P

Comment: I am not sure but what might be the issues is that you flagged it instead of voting (up/down/close), commenting or editing. From what I understood from various meta.se questions I just googled, flagging instead of those other actions will register this as "no action needed" and fail the audit. Just one more reason why I stopped reviewing - the system is broken beyond repair, and that awful patronizing text is just the tip of the iceberg @KatherineVillyard.   (Oh, and I can migrate this to meta.se for bugreporting if you like).

Comment: As of recently, [flagging does not work in FP/NA audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327580/failed-known-bad-audit-after-flagging-because-im-done-was-not-enabled) and you need to do something else. **Never click No Action Needed if action is needed, by you or by anyone.**

Comment: Audits are a waste of a good reviewers time

Comment: @Iain if audits catch even 1 out of 10 robo reviewers and stopping them, it's worth that wasted time, in my opinion.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I deliberately said _good reviewers_ for a reason. Kasperd is demonstrably a good reviewer on SF (where the incident happened).

Comment: @Iain never implied OP here isn't a good reviewer, but that the audits are needed for the bad reviewers, and in my opinion the price (waste of time, failing some by mistake) is worth it.

Comment: Happened to me too; very discouraging :(

Comment: @Iain what on earth are you blabbering about? If you got nothing to say don't say.

Comment: @ShadowWizard exactly my point !

Comment: @kasperd This could very well be an issue, I've faced it twice. See Nathan's thread

Comment: *but that the audits are needed for the bad reviewers, and in my opinion the price (waste of time, failing some by mistake) is worth it* -- that's your opinon, and welcome to it you are of course. However: I've chosen to debug the huge fail in the review process by not bothering with it any more. As the good reviewers (if I may be permitted to flatter myself as well as @kasperd) burn out on this kind of rubbish only the bad reviewers will be left.

Answer (score 12):

[This happened to me too.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327739/6083675) Well, [twice actually.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327751/6083675)

While my first linked answer applies in its entirety here, as a summary
there are just a few things that are very important:

- This is a bug (hacking the HTML doesn't help)
- Do NOT use custom mod flags (although this will enable "I'm done"). It's a related bug, but the mod flags will go through [for real.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327751/6083675)
- Instead, **try to leave a comment**. Or maybe down vote. This is the best way to pass audits like this.

I know it's not ideal, but [they are going to fix this soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281080/why-did-flagging-as-very-low-quality-result-in-audit-failure/281162?noredirect=1#comment913313_281162), since it's a big issue for reviews and moderators.

Comment: Yeah... something's wrong here. We're looking into it.

Comment: Except that *you can't tell whether it's an audit or not, usually,* which is kinda the point.

Answer (score 9):

This was my fault and should be fixed now. I posted some more details [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327896/91).